# Can I use attributes with plist xml?

Tags: ios, xml, titanium, plist

This question should be straight-forward, but I'm having a hard time finding a straight-forward answer.  Can plist elements have attributes?  For example, would

```
<key info="dates">
<array>
<date>2012-06-01T23:03:26Z</date>
<date>2014-02-25T00:05:57Z</date>
<date>2014-05-14T23:06:36Z</date>
</array>
```

be legal in plist xml?

I ask because I'm required to use plist xml for data files in my Titanium app.  Without user-defined tags or attributes, I'm finding it difficult to parse the plist xml, where regular xml would be quite simple because I can use specific tags as selectors.

Comment: How are you reading the plist? If you parse it with an XML parser, it should be OK. If you directly load an `NSArray` with the plist file, the attribute will be lost.

Comment: See `NSPropertyListSerialization` for creating a collection object from a plist data representation.

Comment: I'm using an XML parser, however my concern is with having a proper plist file.

Comment: How else are you using the plist file? If you only parse it with an XML parser, why use a plist file?

Comment: My boss required me to use plist because he wants to use a DTD instead of just random xml that I wrote.  I ended up using one dictionary and then keys and strings only and just grabbing all keys and all strings separately. Then I just iterated and put them together as properties of one object. So it worked out.